# Know if request is from a container in the same network created by docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I want to make request to a container within same network I can do that by a `http` request like

> `http://service-name:port/`

*But how can I know if this http request is coming from a container in the same network created by docker-compose ?*
***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'
services:
  users:
    build: './users'
    ports:
      - '4001:3000'
    volumes:
      - './users:/src/'
  products:
    build: './products'
    ports:
      - '4002:3000'
    volumes:
      - './products:/src/'
  orders:
    build: './orders'
    ports:
      - '4003:3000'
    volumes:
      - './orders:/src/'
  payments:
    build: './payments'
    ports: 
      - '4004:3000'
    volumes: 
      - './payments:/src/'
```

Comment: How would you know this if Docker wasn't involved?  Why do you need to know?

Comment: @DavidMaze If I can make a request to a container within same network. I should know if it's coming from the same network  and not someone hitting http from outside. I could do this to perform some specific task. Like, do this if not internal container calls else do that.
more specific would be blocking a particular http requestion if not from a container within same network.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `https` protocol and client-side certificat to handle your problem

Comment: Okay, that's a good piece of advice, but currently it's under development. Can you explain how it relates to my problem?

Comment: sure, you probably already know server-side certificate. They used to prove your identity thanks to a certificate authority like Thawte or DigiCert. Client-side certificate works the same way but they prove identity of a client. So you just have to create your own Certificate authority, create a certificate for each client who access your server then you are able to identify from which client the request is coming from.